# Does any date in one range exist in another range of dates?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel I have:

```
A1                         B1                             C1                  D1
10/april/2013 01:22:00    13/april/2013 05:24:00    08/april/2013 01:00:00    14/april/2013 08:44:00
```

A1 - B1 is the first date range.
C1 - D1 is the second date range.

So a function could return true in this case.

If range 2 dates were 02/april/2013 and 07/april/2013, would return false.
If range 2 dates were 05/april/2013 and 11/april/2013, true.

How could I check whether ANY DATE FROM A range of dates ALSO EXISTS IN another range of dates?

Comment: I'm not an expert on excel, so it's just an idea. There is an epoch value for each unique date. Why don't you get them and compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula assumes that the earlier date/time comes first.  If that is not the case, use MIN and MAX to ensure the correct comparisons.

```
=AND(D1>=A1,C1<=B1)
```

Comment: Actually, my dates also have the hour together, then the array formule doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the +1.  I read the question differently:  ANY DATE FROM A range of dates ALSO EXISTS IN another range of dates.  So if even one date in the second range is in the first, it should return True

Comment: @Natalia  Just wrap the cell references in the INT function, to remove the time portion.  e.g:  ROW(INDIRECT(INT(C1)&":"&INT(D1)))

Comment: @pnuts  I got my interpretation, if I recall correctly, from the examples.  But now she's added time and I don't know if she also wants to take that into account, or if it can be ignored.

Comment: @Natalia See my last edit.  I have removed the more complicated formulas for clarity.